# How to hide X-PHP-Script header using PHP mail?

Tags: header, sendmail, php

I run a PHP script that sends mails. In header there is an information about script's path. Is there a way to hide it? Is there a way to hide or change the name of a domain from that I send a mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overwriting it to null by adding it as a header:

```
$headers = 'X-PHP-Script: ';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Alternative, you could edit the contents of the header as explained by [this tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/x-php-script/).

Comment: I have tried to overwrite it. It doesn't work. Is this way should work? Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: What about the tutorial I linked to??

Answer (score 1):

Please contact your hoster about the options you have here. It's a security related setting and it's not always intended that you can disable/change it.

Comment: Unfortunately thy told me that they don't have influence on this situation and I should change something in my script.

Comment: @Delicja: And what did they told you to change in your script?

Comment: They are responsible for maintenance of servers so I'm not supposed them to tell me what I should change in my scripts. On the other hand I don't agree with them. You have right. I check in PHP options and they can change/disable this path in server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it work

```
// prevent user/script details being exposed in X-PHP-Script header 
$oldphpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$oldremoteaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = "/"; 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; 

// send the email 
mail($to, $subject, $message[, $additional_headers[, $additional_parameters]]) 

// restore obfuscated server variables 
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $oldphpself; 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $oldremoteaddr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The hosting company knows why they want these headers - to spare themselves from spammers.
They usually do not want allow you to change it.